# Number of arrangements of elements without duplicates

Tags: combinatorics

I have, let's say, an array of six elements ${A;A;B;B;C;C}$, and I would like to get all the arrangements of size 2 of this array.
I know that $\frac{6!}{(6-2)!} = 30$, so there is 30 arrangements, which are :$$[(A,A), (A,A), (A,B), (B,A), (A,B), (B,A), (A,C), (C,A), (A,C), (C,A), (A,B), (B,A), (A,B), (B,A), (A,C), (C,A), (A,C), (C,A), (B,B), (B,B), (B,C), (C,B), (B,C), (C,B), (B,C), (C,B), (B,C), (C,B), (C,C), (C,C)]$$

Without duplicates, there are **9** in all: $${(B,A), (A,A), (C,B), (A,B), (C,A), (C,C), (B,C), (A,C), (B,B)}.$$
So my question is: is it possible to compute the number of arrangements without duplicates?

Comment: Hint:  count the cases where the letters don't match and then count the cases where they do.

Comment: Note:  as a matter of notation, all those $'s$ make the expressions hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to reduce the arrays of six elements into a set of three unique elements $(A, B, C)$ so it becomes a **permutation with repetition problem** since now you can generate r-permutations where an element of the set can be used repeatedly. Using the formula for permutation with repetition, $n^r$, where $n$ is the number of elements to be arranged and $r$ is the number of positions where $n$ elements would be arranged.

Arranging set $(A, B, C)$ into two positions would mean $3^2=9$ ways of arranging the set where element repetition is allowed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it solves my question. But if it wasn't arrangements but combinations, how would it be? Could take at this question [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3557620/number-of-combinations-of-elements-without-duplicates)? Thank you again.